# Why does it take so long for Eclipse to connect to a JUnitRunner process when IPv6 is enabled?

Tags: java, ipv6, sockets

When IPv6 is enabled on my computer, half a minute passed between starting a new JUnit process and the test tree appearing in the JUnit view.

When I disable IPv6, the tests appear immediately.

What I see is that the process is created and then hangs ca. 30s in `SocketImpl.connect()`. With `netstat`, I can see a line like this:

```
tcp6       0      1 fe80::xxxx:xxxx:x:51019 ::1:48469               SYN_SENT
```

Why does that happen?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

The runner process is listening only on `127.0.0.1`, the IPv4 loopback address, but Eclipse is trying to connect to `localhost` – which can be either `127.0.0.1` or `::1`, the latter being IPv6 loopback. On most operating systems, IPv6 is enabled, it will be preferred, causing Eclipse to try IPv6 `::1` first.

Since JUnitRunner is not listening on any IPv6 address, the OS should reject attempted connections with a TCP RST (or *mayyybe* ICMP "Port Unreachable" if properly firewalled). However, you probably have a firewall configuration that is silently dropping such attempts, which means the client (Eclipse) will be waiting for a reply that is never sent.

First check your firewall configuration (`ip6tables`) – there is no reason for it to block loopback connections in any way. Test with the firewall temporarily disabled. If nothing helps, check if Eclipse can be configured to use `127.0.0.1`, or if JUnit can be configured to listen on both IPv6 and IPv4.

Comment: :-/ The `netstat` line above says Eclipse isn't trying to use loopback at all.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: But `::1` *is* IPv6 loopback.

Comment: Ah! I completely missed the right side. Why isn't it showing "::1:51019 ::1:48469"?

Comment: I checked with `ip6tables`: There are no rules and all three chains have the policy "ACCEPT"

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why it is showing a fe80: address. Does `ping6 ::1` reach loopback correctly?

Comment: Yes, `ping6 ::1` works.